# System.IO.IOExceptions Could not complete the operation since a file already exist in this path

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, file-copying

I am trying to copy the file from ftp to local and I am using the code below to do my file copy function and in doing so i am getting an error that files already exist is there any way that i can bypass this and if the file exist it just say do nothing otherwise do the file copy or overwrite the file copied.

```
    Docopy = True
    If Docopy Then
    ' I want some function here so he can tell that file exist
    ' Write now i am using Kill(CopyTo) but it only works once
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(CopyFrom, CopyTo, UserName, Password)
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

There's some extra parameters you can use for that:

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(CopyFrom, CopyTo, UserName, Password, False, 100, True)
```

- 5th parameter shows a UI or not
- 6th parameter is a timeout parameter
- 7th parameter is an overwrite parameter

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127879(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the file exists before you do the copy.

```
Docopy = True
If Docopy Then
    ' I want some function here so he can tell that file exist
    If FileExists("ThisFilenameToTest.txt") = True Then Kill(CopyTo)
    'copy the file
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(CopyFrom, CopyTo, UserName, Password)
End If
```

Comment: There is no point to having the `= True` in there. `FileExists` returns a Boolean already, which is exactly what the if statement needs, so you are just making it do unnecesary extra work.

Comment: Maybe so but 5, 6 or 11 years later when you come back to the code it will make it MORE readable. Although this is a simple = TRUE statement, getting into good practice early on makes your code much more readable to anyone working on it after you sign a job and hand the code over. Otherwise you might as well skip naming variables altogether and simply assign a letter instead if you want to shorten code.